# Auto margins don't center image in page

Tags: css, google-chrome, margin, centering

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/XnKDQ/) the image is not centered. Why? My browser is Google Chrome v10 on windows 7, not IE.

```
<img src="/img/logo.png" style="margin:0px auto;"/>
```

Comment: Testing out a style class, I found that this was not working **margin:0 auto;** after some testing found out that if the class name you are adding to an element has the same name as an element this will not work.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

add `display:block;` and it'll work. Images are inline by default

To clarify, the default width for a `block` element is `auto`, which of course fills the entire available width of the containing element.

By setting the margin to `auto`, the browser assigns half the remaining space to `margin-left` and the other half to `margin-right`.

Comment: +1 For being right. Would make a great answer if you elaborated on what is required for `margin:auto` to center an item in the flow. (`display:block` or `display:table`, `position:static` or `position:relative`, etc.)

Comment: @Phrogz agreed; added some explanation.

Comment: Those reading this may also find it useful to add "float" none as having any other kind of float will bust your margin auto.

Comment: But it's still not centered. It's only centered horizontally. I want to center it vertically, but even if I change `0px auto` to just `auto` it still doesn't work.

Comment: Of course not, auto margins are an older "hack" to center content. If you need precise aligning, use a flexbox: `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center` and now your content is horizontally and vertically centered. Or move that to `align-self: center; justify-self: center` on the content itself. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 16):

You can center auto width div using `display:table;`

```
div{
margin: 0px auto;
float: none;
display: table;
}
```

Comment: This works, and I don't know why. Could you explain?

Comment: I've never used this before but it works for me now.

Answer (score 14):

Under some circumstances (such as earlier versions of IE, Gecko, Webkit) and inheritance, elements with `position:relative;` will prevent `margin:0 auto;` from working, even if `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` aren't set.

Setting the element to `position:static;` (the default) may fix it under these circumstances. Generally, block level elements with a specified width will respect `margin:0 auto;` using either `relative` or `static` positioning.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` works just fine on relatively positioned elements as long as they are block elements with no float and a specified width...

Comment: I assume that's sarcasm.  If you edit your answer so that it is not inaccurate I'll remove the downvote.  I've been writing CSS for almost 15 years and can't ever remember auto margins not working to horizontally center relatively positioned fixed width elements - although other properties like `float` and `display` can change that behavior.

Answer (score 11):

In my case the problem was that I had set **min and max width** without **width** itself.

Comment: to recap:  element must be `position:static`, have a fixed `width:` set and be a `display:block` element

Comment: It was width issue for me too - bootstrap automatically set my div to use 100% available

Answer (score 6):

Whenever we don't add width and add `margin:auto`, I guess it will not work. It's from my experience. Width gives the idea where exactly it needs to provide equal margins.

Answer (score 3):

there is a alternative to `margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;` or `margin:0 auto;` for the ones that use `position:absolute;` this is how:
you set the left position of the element to 50% (`left:50%;`) but that will not center it correctly in order for the element to be centered correctly you need to give it a margin of minus half of it`s width, that will center your element perfectly

here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/35ERq/3/

Answer (score 0):

For a bootstrap button:

```
display: table; 
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember someday that I spent a lot of time trying to center a div, using **`margin: 0 auto`**.

I had **`display: inline-block`** on it, when I removed it, the div centered correctly.

As Ross pointed out, it doesn't work on inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

img{display: flex; max-width: 80%; margin: auto;}

This is working for me. You can also use display: table in this case.
Moreover, if you don't want to stick to this approach you can use the following:

img{position: relative; left: 50%;}

Answer (score -1):

put this in the body's css:
  background:#3D668F;
then add:
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
 to the img's css.