# Margin: 0 auto; not working

Tags: html, css

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Tb3sF/.

[I looked at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734199/margin0-auto-not-working).

I've tried the code below (using and not using: display:block and different widths.)

```
.form {
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 700px; 
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**It is centering**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tb3sF/embedded/result/) with `margin:0px auto`, however, since it is 700px, you are not seeing that it is centered within such a small window.

Try and lower it to something like 300px; [**see jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nhH8E/)

Alternatively, you can just use `text-align:center;` [**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/87Sbb/)

Answer (score 1):

It is working, if you stretch the fiddle window, you can confirm that. Also, if you change the width to a smaller size you can also confirm it. Try adding a border, it will help you out with the visualization.