# How do I center an anchor element both vertically and horizontally in a floating div?

Tags: html, css

I know that this has been asked a thousand times before and I apologise for asking again, but I haven't been able to figure this out after a few minutes of searching.

I am trying to centre an anchor element within a `div` element both horizontally and vertically. The basis for this question is as follow.

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div>
    <a href="">Hello</a>
</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: teal;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: 14px;
}
```

Now, I know that I can use `text-align: center;` on the containing `div` to centre the anchor element horizontally and that I can use `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` on the `div` to align it vertically but it doesn't seem to work together, especially when the `div` is set to float left.

How can I achieve this rather simple layout? Also, please elaborate on why what I'm trying doesn't work as I'd like to learn rather than just fix this.

I would prefer not to use `line-height` since it breaks with multi-line text.

http://jsfiddle.net/xHLze/2/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You basically listed the answer in your question, though you may just need to apply the styles to a few different places:

I put `display: table;` on the containing `<div>`, allowing me to set `display: table-cell;` on the `<a>` element, after which I can apply `vertical-align: middle;` to vertically center the text.

I then applied `text-align: center;` to the `<a>` element to horizontally center it.

http://jsfiddle.net/3RfgD/

What I believe you missed is that you should be setting `display: table;` on the `table-cell` elements parent in order for it to work properly. (an element cannot act as the cell of a table if it is not in a table, whether it's an actual table or a CSS one)

Comment: Ah! So that was the issue. How stupid of me! Thank you so much!

Comment: Oooh `table-cell` hmm better then margin 0 auto ! Thanks @Blake learned something new. :D

Comment: Is there a way to then centre the set of boxes?

Comment: @PeterX there are numerous ways you could centre the boxes now, and it would depend on whether you want them centred horizontally, vertically, or both. You can use things like `text-align`, `flexbox`, or `vertical-align` if it's using table display settings. I'd recommend opening a new question if you have a specific centring problem you need to solve

Answer (score 1):

Use margin for your anchor tag to auto align it in the center of your div tag like this:

```
a{margin:0 auto;}
```

This automatically centralizes your text both vertically and horizontally. :) but since anchor tag is inline tag we need to specify it with respect to the div tag like this

```
div a {display:block;
width:50px;}
```

where 50px is with respect to div's width. Check out here [why margin 0 auto doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734199/margin0-auto-not-working)

Comment: @Siddharth oh yes ! It's an anchor tag after all ! I updated the code.you also use the margin 0 auto thingy but it has issues with various browsers.